# How do I configure the route to the add form for a content type created as a bundle class?

Tags: entities, forms, routes

I've got a custom content entity type, created for me by `drush generate` and I'm extending that using bundle classes.  I've got a MyContentType class and a MyBundle class that extends it and provides some additional fields.  I'm able create MyBundle entities just fine with `drush php` or in a kernel test, so I know all that works.  Now I'm trying to create MyBundle entities in the UI.

The annotation for the MyContentType class provides the path to my form handler

`"add" = "Drupal\my_content_type\Form\MyContentTypeForm"`

and a link to the form to add a new entity

`"add-form" = "/my_content_type/add/{my_content_type}"`.

But when I try going to `/my_content_type/add/my_bundle`, I get a `Page not found`.

Following what I see in node.routing.yml, I've got this in my_module.routing.yml

```
my_content_type.add:
  path: '/my_content_type/add/{my_content_type}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Add some content'
    _form: 'Drupal\my_content_type\Form\MyContentTypeForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
  options:
    parameters:
      my_content_type
        type: entity:my_content_type
```

Once I've created and saved one of my entities using drush php, the edit page loads fine.  So, what's the silly little thing I'm missing here?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, the same name for entity type and bundle. And don't use the node entity as example, this was probably the first Drupal 8 entity. Newer entities don't use a routing file, they use a route provider class.

Comment: That's what I was hoping, too, but it's not doing the trick
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\AdminHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     }'''

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `_entity_form` rather than `_form`. See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes (search for `_entity_form`).

Comment: Drat, that looks like just the kind of silly thing I was wondering about, but changing `_form: 'Drupal\my_content_type\Form\MyContentTypeForm'` to `_entity_form: my_content_type.add` didn't do what I hoped it would.

Comment: Maybe it should be `_entity_form: my_content_type.add_form`

Comment: No luck yet.  Time to dig in with xdebug.